# C++ , using strptime and strftime to convert date formats including invalid dates

Tags: c++, date, datetime

Am using strptime and strftime to convert date from one format to another in C++,
Everything works fine for valid input dates but **in case of invalid dates** it just can't work.

Using mktime 'fixes' or changes dates like if there is an invalid day, it automatially changes the month as well. What I want is to convert any input date from one format to another like

if it is **12/22/99** and i want to convert from **mm/dd/yy to dd-mm-yyyy**, it shall convert to **22-12-1999**.

If there is any invalid date, it shall emit 00 and keep the other things in required format,  like  **12/45/01** (in mm/dd/yy) shall convert to **00-12-2001** (in dd/mm/yyyy format since day can't be 45), the problem is strptime, mktime, all changes the value since the tm timestruct works that way, is there any possibility to do that?

A simple use case can be

```
convert mm/dd/yy to dd-mm-yyyy
        03/33/99 -> 00-03-1999
```

I tried my best but strptime just changes the corresponding month in case of a wrong input day. I tried putting 00 in case of a wrong date, but strptime handles 00 differently too, so for each format, it can't work. Really stuck now.

```
    ////////////////////////////////////////////
    // For those  who wants a programming question
    // i repeat, it is a programming question
    /////////////////////////////////////////////


        struct tm timestruct = {0};

          // it can be in any other supported format as well

          char *in = "80-00-11";
          string fromStr("%Y-%d-%m ");
          string toStr("%d/%m/%y");

          char buf[255];

          if(strptime(in, fromStr.c_str(), &timestruct) == NULL ) // invalid date
             strftime(buf, sizeof(buf), toStr.c_str(), &timestruct);
          puts(buf);

  /* The problem is in case of wrong date like the supplied date in char *in.
  i want to leave out the correct parameters of the supplied data, like 
 00/**11/98**, but it changes the **11** to some other value, my problem is i may have day as empty field like given in the code snippet
*/
```

Comment: In 02/29/15, is it the day, the month, or the year that is invalid?

Comment: In addition to what @AlanStokes is getting at, how do you plan to convert 2-digit years to 4-digit years?  If you get a year value of `50`, is that `1950` or `2050`?

Comment: Alan in 2/29/15, if the from format is m/d/y, then definitely d is wrong (29) but if the from format is d/m/y, then month is wrong..that will depend on the specified format

Comment: Mr Llama, you may consider visiting struct tm  to understand the mechanism, it basically adds 1900 to supplied year, so if the to Format in strftime contains yyyy, it'll show 1950 in this case

Comment: Sorry my bad Mr Llama, it shall be 2050, so till 68, it'll show 2068 but after that in current implementation, it'll show 1969, 1970 til 1999

Comment: But all of 2/28/15, 3/29/15 and 2/29/16 are valid; why do you think the error is in the day?

Comment: I don't really know if this would help.  But here is a library that allows invalid dates, and doesn't do anything with them:  http://howardhinnant.github.io/date_v2.html  You would have to do the parsing yourself, deciding upon whatever format to parse.  You could build a date, and then query the date if it is valid or not.  Then output the date in whatever format you want by converting the fields to integers.  It won't do any parsing or formatting for you.  It won't do year windowing for you.  But it will tell you if a y/m/d triple is valid or not.  And it will let you set any field to 0.

Comment: Thats really great Howard. Unfortunately the library supports C++ 11 & 14, and I've to do in C++-99 :( But its good to have this information for future. Appreciate that